# Predicting ecommerce variables based on visitation data - R or Python

Tags: r, predictive-models, forecasting, python

I have 1.5 years worth of e-commerce data (orders and revenue) for 2 countries (US and UK) with daily metrics for visits, unique visitors, and page views. I would like to model these transactions and apply the model to 1.5 years worth of visitation data (visits, unique visitors, and page views) to predict e-commerce for 10 additional countries.

I tried to use the `glm()` function in R, but from what I gather, the outcome variable has to be a binomial.

What would be the best way to solve this problem in R or even Python?

Comment: Not sure why the outcome would have to be binomial. Are the e-commerce data binary (yes/no) or continuous (# or orders and amount of revenue)? There are a number of ways to mode this question though you may want to start by examining multivariate linear regression.

Comment: The outcomes would have to be continuous, as in # of orders and amount of revenue.  Would multivariate linear regression still be the route to go?

Comment: "*from what I gather, the outcome variable has to be a binomial*" - your impression is inaccurate, as the examples under `?glm` indicate (there are Poisson, Gaussian and gamma examples).

Comment: Are you asking about how to *use* R &/or Python to get this done, or about how such models can be fit (& the software is an ancillary issue)? If the former, this Q would be off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)), but on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If your question is primarily statistical, please edit to clarify; if not, flag your Q & we'll migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post, though*).

Comment: @gung it's probably too late to migrate a question asked 3 weeks ago.